# Hosting File Download on Windows Azure

Tags: file, azure, cloud, hosting

I want to host an executable download(.exe) on Azure as my shared hosting provider has issues in handling downloads. I'm little bit confused with the Azure concepts i have created a new Blob and a container.Now how can i upload a file to it?

```
Storage>Blob>Container
```

Should i need to configure other settings to allow simultaneous downloads and where can i see the amount of data downloaded.I just need to host a file just like dropbox and allow it to be downloaded by users,and allowing them to see the progress % of the download

Answer (score 3):

There're so many things here. My recommendation would be to read more about blob storage first. You may find `Windows Azure Training Kit` useful in grasping the concepts about blob storage.

In a nutshell, think of `blob storage` as `file system in the cloud`. If we were to make an analogy with the local file system: computer hard drive = storage account, folder = blob container, file = blob. There's one minor difference - a folder on your computer can contain nested sub folders however blob storage just has a flat hierarchy: `storage account > blob container > blob`. Nesting of blob containers is not supported.

But to quickly answer some of your questions (without overwhelming you :)):

> I have created a new Blob and a container.Now how can i upload a file
>   to it?
>   To upload a blob in the blob container, you could:

- Use one of the many storage explorers available in the market today. They range from open source, commercial (free) and commercial (paid). One of my favorites is Azure Explorer from Cerebrata. It's a free tool. More information about this tool can be found here: http://www.cerebrata.com/labs/azure-explorer
- Blob storage is managed via REST API. What you could do is write code to consume that REST API. More information about it can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179355.aspx.
- Use storage client library: Microsoft provides storage client libraries in various languages. A storage client library is essentially a wrapper over REST API. For example, if you are coming from .Net world, you can take a look at .Net storage client library here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179380.aspx

> Should i need to configure other settings to allow simultaneous
>   downloads

You don't have to do anything specific to allow simultaneous downloads.

> Where can i see the amount of data downloaded

I would say, don't worry about it just yet. As you get more deep into blob storage, you will automatically find an answer to this question. At this time, the answer would simply overwhelm you (sorry, if I sound too preachy :)).

> I just need to host a file just like dropbox and allow it to be
>   downloaded by users,and allowing them to see the progress % of the
>   download

One of the purpose of blob storage is just that. What you could do is upload a blob and get the blob's URL and you can share that URL with the people you want to download the blob. Just make sure that when you create a blob container, make its ACL as `Blob` or `Public`. This link may be helpful in understanding this concept: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179354.aspx.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav,I don't want to share the whole blob,just the file.I think the Azure team could have come up with something simpler like the Amazon cloudfront

Comment: Essentially file is known as blob in Windows Azure blob storage. Think of blob storage as file system in the cloud. If we were to make an analogy with the local file system: computer hard drive = storage account, folder = blob container, file = blob. When I say you create a URL for the blob, I actually meant URL for a file. HTH.

Comment: I tried uploading the file with Cerebrata Azure Explorer after the uploading dialog box appeared and waiting,an error dialog pop-upped saying 'One or more errors occurred' There is a blob container called downloads and i tried to upload the file inside that

Comment: I suggest you get in touch with Cerebrata support regarding the error. They may be able to help you with the error.

Comment: @techno - Amazon's Cloudfront is edge-caching, similar to Azure's CDN. This is not a replacement for storage, whether looking at AWS or Azure. Once you read up on blob storage (per links Gaurav gave you), you'll see how simple and straightforward it is to use, and you'll also see that each blob contains a single entity (call it a file), so yes, you will want to share *the whole blob*.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I see that you are from the Azure Team,Why don't you guys add a way to explore data via the browser like the FTP Client Provided by Cpanel,it could be much better.

Comment: @techno - It's already there. If you go to Windows Azure Portal, you will be able to browse storage. Other alternative would be using Server Explorer in Visual Studio (I think you would need to install Windows Azure .Net SDK for that).